# can't edit label text in different .cs

Tags: text

```
        public static void CalibrateLoop()
    {
        communicator comport = new communicator();
        while ( Variables.calibrating )
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            if (comport.connect(9600, "VRCONNECTREQUEST", 1, 0, 0))
            {
                form2.label7.Text = "Connection Successful - Connected to  " + comport.port;
            }
            else
            {
                Form2.Hide();
                var form1 = new Form1();
                form1.Closed += (s, args) => Form1.Close();
                form1.Show();
            }
            //label2.Text = comport.message(2, 0, 0);

        }
        //Variables.minHand[0] = 20;
    }
```

I made this real quick simple piece of code in communicator.cs, the issue is that it refuses to edit the "label7.text" and also the "form2.hide()" doesn't seem to work. The Label7 is located in form2.

Anyone can help me out with this issue? been struggeling to find an answer allover internet

Comment: What exception it gives? you seen that using debugger?

Comment: -The name 'label7' does not exist in the current context
-an object referencce is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'control.hide()'

Comment: Just give reference to that particular file or include respective namespace

Comment: Thanks, seem to have a big part of it fixed. Last question is that I made a file called form2.cs where a label is located with the name "label7" now I want to have that label being edited in that piece of script. It does work when I use [label7.text = "test"] in form2.cs but I can't get it to work when I do [form2.label7.text = "test"]

Comment: I am trying to understand your 2nd question. plz wait i will give you solution @Zannaza

Comment: You can do label7.text = "sometext"  in pageload. so that it will change text when page gets load.

Comment: I wish to have it changed in a seperated .cs, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give proper Reference to that particular file or include a respective Namespace.